# Hahn Banach for the weak-* topology

Tags: functional-analysis

I need help with this problem:

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $A,B \subseteq X^*$ non empty, convex and $A$ $\sigma(X^*,X)$ open. Then exists $x \in X$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$f(x)\leq \alpha \leq g(x) \quad \forall f \in A, \ g \in B$$

(I only have the norm version of Hahn-Banach)

---

My attempt:

Since $A$ is $\sigma(X^*,X)$ open then is strongly open and we can use Hahn-Banach on $X^*$, hence will exist $h \in X^{**}$ such that 
$$h(f) \leq \alpha \leq  h(g) \quad \forall f \in A, \ g \in B$$

I want to prove that $h$ is $\sigma(X^*,X)$ continuous and then $h$ will be represented by a element $x \in X$

Comment: Note that $X^{\ast}$ with the topology $\sigma(X^{\ast},X)$ is a locally convex topological vector space. In this setting, Hahn-Banach provides a linear functional that is continuous with respect to $\sigma(X^{\ast},X)$ (not merely the norm topology).

Comment: @user90803: Which version of Hahn-Banach do you have available? It would be helpful, if you mention this in your question.

Comment: thanks for the comment, edited.